# Touchpad can not be used and missing from Device Manager

Tags: windows-10, laptop, mouse, touchpad

Last night my laptop was working properly. When I used it this morning there is some problem with the touchpad: There is no cursor displayed. I think the touchpad is disabled so I press `fn+F9` but nothing happens except `TouchPad is disabled` is displayed. I try to solve it in Device Manager but my touchpad is missing. I look at `Setting>Device` but the `TouchPad` menu is gone. The wireless mouse is working.

I re-installed Touchpad driver from Asus but still not working. Last, I update windows 10 but it changed nothing.

How to fix it?

Asus X441UBR
Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Look in Device Manager under Mice and Other Pointing Devices (I think your Touchpad will be there if it exists.  If not there and not anywhere, then it has gone defective.

Comment: No, it does not exist. Exactly, no "Mice and Other Pointing Device", except i plug in external mouse. I got "Asus Precision Touchpad"(as hidden device) under "Human Interface Device", and try to update, uninstall, and reinstall, but nothing happend.

Comment: You have a hardware issue and need to get the machine serviced.